# add group info to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  6
1  1  2  4  8
2  1  2  4  6
3  1  2  3  8
```

I would like to group this `DataFrame` by the column `a, b, d`,  add a column to the original `df` to mark which group it belongs to, the output should be

```
   a  b  c  d  g
0  1  2  3  6  0
1  1  2  4  8  1
2  1  2  4  6  0
3  1  2  3  8  1
```

Comment: Sorry, changed dupe for `df['g'] = df.groupby(['a','b','d']).ngroup()`

Comment: @jezrael quite useful, thank you.